# How are the binary data inside a certain format parsed?

Tags: lexical-analysis, linguistics

Considering a binary data (video/images/audio/executable) can be regarded as a long sequence of random bytes,
when the data is inside a special format (SQL, BOLB in database, MP3, JSON, XML etc), how does the parser know that a special char(or sequence of chars, like {,},\t,space,EOF) is used in formatting, not a part of the binary data and vice versa?

Also, I am not quite sure which category this question fits in, so I put lexical analysis and linguistics. What subject/fields of computer science studies this?

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed an odd place for this question. I'm a little unclear on exactly what you're asking here, but in sum, not all binary data (assuming you mean machine readable data) are equal. For instance: audio, images, and video are not executable data, they are parsed data; as such they are handled differently.

Also, "binary data" are not as arbitrary as you might think upon opening a hex editor for the first time :). Executables are structured into DATA and CODE segments, so with those flags the computer knows how to treat things appropriately. As for the other three types you mentioned, they are all structured differently depending upon their file format, which is why so many different file formats are out there! The executable program which parses these files knows how to handle them based upon information contained in the code about the file format, which of course means that the program has to know how to handle the file format and have info on how it is segmented to load it properly, which is why you can't open an MP3 in Microsoft Paint.

As for the study of file formats and data storage, that has applications in a lot of areas, it's not really a field unto itself so much as a topic that comes up in a lot of areas. Information Theory,  Reverse Engineering, Natural Language Processing, and many others have uses for understanding different file types and how they store data. Anyhow, this was only a brief, cursory explanation, and there's plenty of things you can google (try .exe file formats or .jpg/.png file formats to start).